# Completely custom GUI's (Preferably in Java)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

Im looking to create a GUI along the lines of:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRFA9.jpg

No boarders or title bar. Very clean and simple. 
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#close

Comment: use  setUndecorated(true) on your JFrame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with AWT or Swing by using [`Frame#setUndecorated(boolean)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29):

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Title");
frame.setUndecorated(true);
frame.pack();
frame.setSize(800, 600);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you soo much <3

Answer (score 3):

In Java you can achieve this with SWT, no hacks involved. You create a `Shell` where you set the appropriate style flags, and you've got yourself a window with no "trims", as they are called. Maybe Swing has the equivalent.